# Xcode NSArrayController selectedIndex bind to a custom view

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I like to bind a method to load a custom view to my NSArrayController. All bindings to the values works fine.

[image]

I also add a simple method for testing to my NSArrayContoller. If I change the method to a IBAction and bind it to the button, it works fine.

```
- (IBAction)loadView:(id)sender
{
    //Works fine by binding to example button
}
```

Due to it has to be loaded by selecting a row without by clicking the button:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    Project *Project = [[self selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *dtmVon = [Project valueForKey:@"dtmVon"];
    NSLog(@"HERE: loadView %@", dtmVon); 

    //Add the new pie chart...
    NSView* scatter = [self getTheGraph];

    [_scatterView addSubview: scatter];
    [scatter setFrame:[_scatterView bounds]];

    [_scatterView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [scatter setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];   
}
```

How I can bind the method to my selected row?

Comment: You want `loadView` to be called when you click a row in a table view?   That's a delegate function, not a something you'd do with bindings.

Comment: Perfect, you're right. The <NSTableViewDelegate> delegate works fine with <tableViewSelectionDidChange>

Comment: Think of bindings as the datasource, and the delegate as controlling the view and user interaction.  So it's quite common to have an array controller coupled with a controller that implements NSTableViewDelegate

Comment: @stevesliva if you could move your comments in an answer, user3152121 could accept it and this question could move out of the unanswered list.